# What's the difference between ruby gems for bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, rubygems

What's the difference between gems:

- bootstrap-sass (downloads 8,309,861)
- bootstrap-sass-rails (downloads 236,886)
- twitter_bootstrap_sass (downloads 6,011)

and which gem to use better in rails app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[twitter_bootstrap_sass](https://github.com/thedelchop/twitter_bootstrap_sass)** was the first bootstrap gem provided by the community. It is deprecated and no longer being used.

**[bootstrap-sass-rails](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails)** was the official bootstrap gem. It was provided by the community and endorsed by twitter until it was deprecated in 2014 and replaced by the bellow bootstrap-sass

**[bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)** is the official bootstrap gem provided by twitter for rails users. It is the currently recommended gem for adding bootstrap assets to your rails application.

## Note (update as of Rails 5.1.2)

The currently recommended way of including frontend assets is through [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/). Yarn is a frontend package manager that is shipped with Rails 5.1.2. If you want to do it the Rails way, just run `yarn add bootstrap` in your project directory and Yarn will handle downloading bootstrap for you. Then you can import bootstrap .css and .js files in your application manifests.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПальгуев if you find my answer to be the correct one, would you kindly mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you use the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

The bootstrap-sass-rails gem is deprecated and they recommend that you use bootstrap-sass directly (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails)